# Laravel is adding/removing characters when using HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https, binary

I have some zip files in my laravel project and they were downloaded by simple method

```
return response()->download($path);
```

now I added forcing https to the website with this:

```
if (!(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ||
   $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) ||
   isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
   $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'))
{
   $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
   header('Location: ' . $redirect);
   exit();
}
```

and now I can't read the zip files, they seem corrupted.

I opened one of them in hex editor, and I see that there is an additional 0a0a character at the beginning.

I have no idea why this happens and what that means. And especially how to fix it, without editing the downloaded files.

Comment: 0A is the hexadecimal value for a newline character. So you have php code that generates two newline characters before the real binary data is sent. Look for blank lines before the first `<?php` in your source files or other places where you may have introduced newlines into the output. Your source code versioning tool can probably tell you where it is.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your headers try looking at this blog post and see if that is the fix to your issues.

https://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/

```
<?php // HTTP Headers for ZIP File Downloads
// https://perishablepress.com/press/2010/11/17/http-headers-file-downloads/

// set example variables
$filename = "Inferno.zip";
$filepath = "/var/www/domain/httpdocs/download/path/";

// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. If that page contains a solution, write it here and use the link as a reference. If that link changes/gets deleted, this answer will be useless for future visitors.